# Getting ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy error

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I used the modal

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :standards
```

My Second modal

```
class Standard < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :subject
  belongs_to :school
```

I wanted to extract the list of schools subject for that in view i am doing

```
- @school.standards.each do |standard|
  = f.association :subject, collection: standard.subject
```

I am getting the list but, i am getting the separate dropdown for separate standards rather then a school subject list, i am new to rails please help. Thanks in advance

I tried this

```
= @school.standards.joins(:subject => [:taggings => [:tag]]).map{|i| i.subject}
```

but i am not getting the list of subjects instead i am getting

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 85, name: "eee">
```

Comment: I have updated it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

In the views, to access and edit the list, you have to use:

```
subject_list
```

instead of

```
subject
```

I hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

In model School add:

```
has_many :subjects, through: :standards
```

And then in your view:

```
f.association :subjects
```

Comment: I have updated the code now i am using with acts_as_taggable_on is there any way to do it thanks